# Can't disable 'workspaces on primary display only'

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

Recently installed ubuntu 14.04 and gnome shell 3.10.4 on a dsktop with 2 screens connected.

When switching workspaces (ctrl + alt + up/down) I want both displays to change, but only the primary display changes (the secondary stays static with the same windows.)

Installing 'gnome-tweak-tool', turning 'Workspaces only on primary display' off did not help.

Couldn't find any other suggestion online.

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So...
The next thing that happened was that I tried rebooting my machine and sort of failed, I was informed the graphics weren't properly configured.
Rebooted to shell,
switched back from 'gdm' to 'lightdm', and now machine is running and workspaces span both monitors.

(Woohoo!)